# Why I am not notified if someone commented?

Tags: support

I have strange issue but i think that it is due to SO's coding that we don't get notification of comment until we have have tagged in comment. But i thought that once someone commented on post or answer. He/she will get notification of each comment as he / she participated in that discussion. Is it?

> I was not notified of comment and the questioner was waiting for me.
>   But IDK, why opened that question (just was wandering on SO) and saw comment there that he was
>   asking for assistance for the code I gave him

Comment: PS. It's not Stacky. It's SO or StackOverflow.

Comment: @Diago Stack Overflow really... ;)

Comment: @Bart Valid point, outside of the edit timer unfortunately.

Comment: Aw, I rather like 'Stacky' `:)`