# Why are we not notified when new comments appear after we leave a comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, notifications

First, let me start by saying this is the same question asked [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168074/why-i-am-not-notified-if-someone-commented).  That question was marked as a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work), but it's not a duplicate.  The poster was asking about this scenario:

1. OP asks a question.
2. Some other user leaves a comment.
3. I leave a comment asking a follow-up
   question.
4. The OP leaves another comment answering my follow-up
   question, but **doesn't** @reply to me.

In this scenario, I don't get notified of the new comment.

Of course, when someone @replies to anything, the user in that @reply gets a notification.  But when a follow-up comment doesn't contain an @reply, the previous commenters have no idea that there's new information.  Sure, the OP should @reply, but when they don't, it could leave them hanging without further help.  Is this just the way things are meant to be, and it's "tough luck" for the OP if they don't @reply?

Comment: You *are* notified, if nobody else (except OP) comments earlier.

Comment: To clarify, you're saying that if I comment first on someone else's question, I'll be notified of other comments, even if I don't get @replied to?  If you're correct, then you should have received a notification regarding this comment.  Did you?

Comment: ...until someone else (except OP, again) gets involved, the system guesses that OP meant to reply you and you receive all his comments notifs there.

Comment: That'd make for a pretty good answer, @nicael.

Comment: @Shog Okay, posted :)

Answer (score 7):

It's just not really the way it works.

If you are an only user who leaves the comment on a question except OP, then you get notifications when OP posts the comments until someone else decides to participate - the system hopes that OP won't talk to themselves.

So don't worry - OP isn't "punished" for not knowing that it'd be safe to use @replies when addressing someone.

Comment: You're a little mixed up about my concern.  I'm concerned that those of us who leave follow-up questions in comments aren't getting notified when the OP replies to those comments.  It's happened to me a few times lately, and I find it a little annoying that I have to revisit the question -- essentially "babysitting" it, to see if the OP has replied.

Comment: @digijim You should've got the notification once OP replied, could you give me some specific link to the one of those questions?

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/55081/psd-to-htmlcss-my-margins-are-wrong#comment80436_55081

Comment: @digijim Ok, please reread: **if you are an only user who leaves the comment on a question except OP, then you get notifications when OP posts the comments until someone else decides to participate...**

Comment: I don't need you to repeat what you already said in bold.  It doesn't get the point across any better.  I 100% understand that statement already.  You don't understand my statement.  So let me rephrase the "problem":  If you are the SECOND, or THIRD, etc. person to comment, then you DON'T get notified when the OP leaves a new comment unless they @reply to you.  I don't know how to word this any clearer.  I'm rephrasing my question now.

Comment: @dig What? And what if OP decided to reply that way the first user? Or do you propose to flood the inbox of any commentator with OP's comment?

Comment: Doesn't it make sense to notify commentators when the OP leaves a comment, regardless of whether the commentator was first?  The OP may be answering a follow-up question from said commentator, but unless the OP @replies to the commentator, the commentator would never know unless they revisit the question. Personally, I wouldn't consider this "flooding" my inbox.  I would consider it keeping me in the loop on a question I'm trying to contribute an answer to.